# Mustache Template using Ajax mysql request outputting to view

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mustache

I'm trying to apply sql queries to a Mustache template. I'm querying a users table within the laravel database. So far I have it returning name: 'John' lastname 'Smith'

My api.php page is getting is querying the database and returning the data as json. No problem here.

```
<?php 

  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";

  $databaseName = "laravel";
  $tableName = "users";

  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");  
  //fetch result            
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          

  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Then I have a client.html page in which I am attempting to create the template. Is it because I'm returning json without any structure just pure data? Is there a way to specify what data I want to return via queries. I'm currently querying all the data and trying to template it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2> Client example </h2>
  <h3>Output: </h3>

<script id="projectstpl" type="text/template">
  <div id="output">
  {{#projects}}
    <div class="project">
      <h3>{{name}}</h3>
      <h4>{{lastname}}</h4>
    </div>
  {{/projects}}
  </div>
</script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle/2.9999.8/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.0/mustache.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script id="source" type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'api.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data) {         //on recieve of reply

        var template = $('#projectstpl').html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#output').html(html);
      } 
    });
  }); 

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does the JSON look like?

Comment: @Shikiryu ["1","John","Smith"]

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with mustache.js. But, based on its demo, https://mustache.github.io/#demo

It seems that your JSON shouldn't simply be ["1", "John", "Smith"] but something like this ["projects": [{"name" : "John", "lastname" : "Smith"}]].

I'm sure you can remove {{#projects}} from your HTML and instead have the JSON simply as ["name" : "John", "lastname" : "Smith"].